# Angularjs + node + socket.io on localhost

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io, localhost

I'm using an AngularJs, node & socket.io to write an app where I want to have some shared data in my different clients. I'm looking at this example: https://github.com/mhevery/angular-node-socketio

I get everything up and running and it works fine if I go to the location of my index.html in my file system (c:/user/angularnodesocket/index.html), but when I go to localhost:8888 the site still shows but the angular stuff is not interpretated.

I get this error on localhost

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8888/bower_components/angular/angular.js". localhost/:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8888/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1
```

Can anyone help me with what's going on here?

//G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that example you are using the following code

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        fs.readFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html', function (err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
                response.end(data);
        });
}).listen(8888);
```

returns index.html whatever the request is. Your browser requests angular.js file, but index html is returned instead which causes the error messages you see.

You have to modify server.js code to support static files.